# Do i need to free the memory after using a string list with object type

Tags: c#, string, list, object, memory

I want to create a collection class that can collect any type of data (string, int, float). So I decided to use a `List<object>` structure to store any kind of data.

Since using a List structure is safer (managed) than creating an unmanaged array, I want to create a List structure so it can hold any kind of data... but I have some concerns that if I create a `List<object>` structure and try to hold some strings, there could be memory leaks because of string type..

So do I have to do somethings after using (emptying) the List and deallocate the strings individualy or does .Net already handle that...

Is there a nicer method for creating general collection class?

Comment: Possible answer on memory management using Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567979/how-to-free-memory-in-java

Comment: Try using dynamic list, see if this helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600810/how-to-create-a-list-with-a-dynamic-object-type-c-sharp

Comment: What makes you think that using a `string` type will result in a memory leak in .Net?  .Net will handle the deallocation and cleanup of memory on your behalf and in this circumstance you do not need to consider it.

Comment: You seem to have a little misconception. If you create an array in C# (e.g. `string[]`), it's not "_unmanaged_". The garbage collector manages the array.

Answer (score 1):

You won´t need to GarbageCollect any objects on your own as long as you really need to, but according to your post that´s not the case here, actually this is only necessary in a few cases (you may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect) what these cases might be). 
However .NET frees any memory to which no references exist (indepenedend if you have an int, a string or any custom object), thus if you leave the scope of your array, list or whatever you use the contained elements will be eliminated at some none-deterministic point of time by the GC, but you won´t take care for this.

What you mean by managed and unmanaged is probably the fact, that a List is a bit more dynamic as it can change its size depending on the current number of elements. If this number exceeds a given maximum the list automatically increaes by a given factor. An array is fixed in size however. The term "unmanaged" however relies to C++ e.g., C#-Code is allways managed code (which means there is a garbage-collector e.g.). See [Wikipedia on Managed Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code)