# Display list in asp.net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I receive a List of objects in my controller from my asp.net web application. How can I pass this list to the view2 and display it?

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController:Controller
{
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
  WCF.CommunicationServiceClient Client = new WCF.CommunicationClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService");
  List<object> objectlist = Client.GetList("_something_");

  return View("ShowView");
 }
}
```

My biggest Problem is that this "object" is defined in another solution.

Comment: I recommend that you take a tutorial on ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My biggest Problem is that this "object" is defined in another solution.

You should define your object in another project. For example, 'DataTransferObjects'. Then you add a reference to this project in both your WCF Server project and your MVC (WCF Client) project. This way the class will be known by both.

In your DTO project:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code would be:

```
public class HomeController:Controller
{
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
  WCF.CommunicationServiceClient Client = new WCF.CommunicationClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService");
  List<MyClass> objectlist = Client.GetList("_something_");

  return View("ShowView", objectlist);
 }
}
```

And your ShowView:

```
@model List<MyClass>

@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].MyProperty)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the objectlist as view model to the view.  I think the dynamic class will come in handy when defining your @model on the view.

Basic MVC really.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [strongly typed view](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/strongly-typed-views-in-mvc/) then pass object to it like `return View(objectlist );`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic instead of Object in the List like this, As you don't know what the object have grab.

```
 public class HomeController:Controller
 {
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
     WCF.CommunicationServiceClient Client = new WCF.CommunicationClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService");
     List<dynamic> objectlist = Client.GetList("_something_");
     return View("ShowView");
    }
 }
```

Know more about **dynamic** [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Also one other Question that may be relates
[List with Dynamic Object Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600810/how-to-create-a-list-with-a-dynamic-object-type-c-sharp)