# Assigning a type .net

Tags: c#, .net, types

```
Type T;

if (report.ReportType == 0) {
    T = typeof(ReportTempHum);
} else if (report.ReportType == 11){
    T = typeof(ReportVibration);
}

List<(Type)T> result = new List<(Type)T>();
```

I'm trying to assign a type into a List in terms of a reportType condition. But some errors.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Edit: Error; 
Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
Error CS0118  'T' is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: What error are you getting and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've answered with what seems to me to be the most likely issue, but will adjust if you provide the error

Comment: I have just added the error message

Comment: have you tried List<typeof(T)>?

Comment: Thank you @JamesHughes, but does not work out.

Comment: Please see my answer, after a bit of digging I don't think this can be done unless you do something like @OriNachum's answer, resort to dynamics, or use reflection to generate your new classes OTF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure ReportTempHum and ReportVibration have the same interface.

```
List<IReportType> result;
        if (report.ReportType == 0) {
            result = new List<ReportTempHum>();
        } else if (report.ReportType == 11){
            result = new List<ReportVibration>();
        }

        //note to verify List is not null!
```

Comment: Might be worth switching on the `report.ReportType` if there are many options too.

Comment: Yes. That's another way to solve the problem. But I am looking for a solution by using the "Type". Thank you.

Comment: Try using object (Or other closest class) then, and every time you work with the list's data, cast it to T.

Comment: @NewPHPer _But I am looking for a solution by using the "Type"_ you are trying to solve a problem in wrong way. why not use polymorphism which is most important thing in OOP, even name of your classes are telling they must have same base like `Report` class

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this can't be done:

The whole point of generics is to provide compile-time safety. Consequently, type objects cannot be used as generic parameters.

Please see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667999/4700841) for more information.

Comment: In his case `T` is a Type object, which you cannot use as a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get a List of Type T. However, keep in mind it isn't strongly typed!

```
Type T;

if (report.ReportType == 0) {
    T = typeof(ReportTempHum);
} else if (report.ReportType == 11){
    T = typeof(ReportVibration);
}

var constructedListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(T);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use dynamic as the argument:

```
var result = new List<dynamic>();
```

For more inframtion see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

See also this related question: [How to create a List with a dynamic object type C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600810/how-to-create-a-list-with-a-dynamic-object-type-c-sharp)

Comment: Downvoted. Usually if you have to use `dynamic` your program design is usually wrong. `dynamic` was not invented to be used in regular C# code. Generally it should only be used when working with COM, dynamic typed language libraries, ASP.NET MVC views etc. not something like this.